# encode as CSV then ZIP in golang

Tags: go, stream

How do I CSV encode and then zip?

Is there a way to chain a writer to another?  Must I create a new buffer in between writers?

```golang
var buf bytes.Buffer

zipWriter := zip.NewWriter(&buf)
csvwriter := csv.NewWriter(zipWriter) // <--- zip writer doesn't implement `io.writer`

csvwriter.Write([]string{"a", "b\"fwr", "c"})
csvwriter.Write([]string{"a", "e", "ww"})
csvwriter.Flush()

println(buf.String())
```

Comment: zip is an archive format, so have to add a file before you can write content. Use [Create](https://golang.org/pkg/archive/zip/#Writer.Create) or [CreateHeader](https://golang.org/pkg/archive/zip/#Writer.CreateHeader).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`zip` produces a structured zip file with a directory structure, which means you need to create and add each file independently.

An [example playground](https://play.golang.org/p/pN5Z04_lavM) demonstrates how to add your CSV file. It also demonstrates opening the compressed zip file and enumerating the files.

---

If you want to `gzip` the file as a single compressed stream, like:

```sh
$ gzip somefile.csv
```

to produce `somefile.csv.gz`

Then you can do the following as demostrated by this [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/gOj2TiAds0S)

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "compress/gzip"
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
)

func main() {
    var buf bytes.Buffer

    zipWriter := gzip.NewWriter(&buf)
    csvwriter := csv.NewWriter(zipWriter)

    csvwriter.Write([]string{"a", "b\"fwr", "c"})
    csvwriter.Write([]string{"a", "e", "ww"})
    csvwriter.Flush()
    zipWriter.Flush()
    zipWriter.Close()

    fmt.Println(buf.Bytes())
    zipReader, _ := gzip.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(buf.Bytes()))
    d, err := ioutil.ReadAll(zipReader)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("err", err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(d))
}
```

Comment: First example playground was what I needed.  thanks!